Shopify oauth redirect_uri and application url must have matching hosts
I'm trying to create a Shopify app and getting one of two errors.  On one machine I get
redirect_url and application url must have matching hosts.

On the other I get
redirect_uri is not whitelisted

In shopify I've verified my URLs several times
Application URL

https://myapplication.domain.com/shopify

Allowed redirection URLs
   https://myapplication.domain.com/shopify/install.php
   https://myapplication.domain.com/shopify/get_token.php
   https://myapplication.domain.com

I've tried with and without trailing slashes on the Application URL

No change in behavior


I've tried removing the https:// from the front

This complains of a bad URL


I've confirmed no typos in the URLs
The errors don't change on the 2 machines on each attempt to update the code.

How do I start troubleshooting or what additional info can I provide?
